# Animate opacity on hover (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, opacity

We have a link:

```
<a href="#">
    Some text
    <span style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: url(image.png); overflow: hidden; opacity: 0;"></span>
</a>
```

And we want to change opacity of `<span>` with some animation, when the link is hovered.

How would we do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('a:has(span)').hover(
    function() { $('span', this).fadeIn(); },
    function() { $('span', this).fadeOut(); }
);
```

Answer (score 46):

Another possible solution:

```
$("a span").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1});
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0});
});
```

If you use fadeOut(), the span will collapse, this way it won't

EDIT

This is much better:

```
$('a:has(span)').hover(function() { 
    $('span', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); 
},function() { 
    $('span', this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0}); 
});
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong - he wants the effect to appear when the link is hovered, not the span.  However, you have a good point.

Answer (score 3):

### Use [.fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/):

```js
$( 'a' ).hover(
    function() { $( this ).fadeTo( 'fast', '1'); },
    function() { $( this ).fadeTo( 'fast', '.4'); }
);
```

### Demo: see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/2u2nsb32/2)

Comment: Your original logic is still conveyed. +1