# Jquery animate while hover

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm looking for a very basic feature: I want to animate a div in it's position while the mouse hovers over a certain area of the window. 
I've already figured out how and when to fire off the animate function the problem is, that it's limited in its time. I'm looking for a way to move the div relative to it's position while hovering.

Cheers, janik

Edit:

I've created a JDfiddle. Didn't know about that before. jsfiddle.net/Ru2mZ/7 To render out my problem: I want a continuous movement or animation of an object while the mouse is over the button. So a basic animation like $('#id').animate({left: 100},100) wouldn't work since it's limited to a fixed end position and a fixed amount of time.

Comment: Might be worth putting up a JSFiddle of what you've done so far...much quicker / easier for someone to help that way.

Comment: Refer this existing question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127458/animate-opacity-on-hover-jquery][1] If this help you, that's great. [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127458/animate-opacity-on-hover-jquery

Comment: Thats right timbo. JSfiddle URL is **http://jsfiddle.net/**

Answer (score 2):

```
        $('#someDiv').bind('mouseenter', function () {
            this.iid = setInterval(function () {
                aniDiv();
            }, 25);
        }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
            this.iid && clearInterval(this.iid);
        });
        function aniDiv() {
            $('#someDiv').animate({ marginLeft: '-=200px' },10);
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation of the hover function.
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Basically, you have to

```
$("#div-id").hover(
  function () {
    //Do whatever you want to any element when the mouse is on the div with id: div-id. If you want to change anything related to the div being hoved, use the $(this) selector.
  },
  function () {
    //Do whatever you want to any element when the mouse was on the div with id: div-id and leaves it. If you want to change anything related to the div being hoved, use the $(this) selector.
  }
);
```

Comment: I'm absolutely aware of how the hover function works. The Problem is much more complex and referrs to the animate function.